# Canonical form of a Matrix question involving a conjugacy

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

How do i find the canonical form of this matrix, my attempt is to use it in a conjugacy for flow.

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0 \\ -1&0&0\\ 1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

do i need to characteristic polynomial determinant find the eigenvalues then eigenvectors?

call the matrix $T$ where T is the matrix of my eigen vectors then find $T^{-1}$ reduce the matrix above to RREF where A RREF = $A_{r}$

$ TA_{r}T^{-1}$

If so can you please show me how to do this or link me to a similiar example?

EDIT

if so $(1-\lambda) (\lambda^{2} +1)$
$\lambda_{1} = 1, \lambda_{2} = i, \lambda_{3} = -i$

the problems lies in $lambda_{1} = 1$

we have

$$\begin{pmatrix} -1&1&0 \\ -1&-1&0\\ 1&1&(1-1)=0\end{pmatrix}$$

And im not sure where to go from here

my best guess it the vector $$V_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0\\ t\end{pmatrix}$$

for $\lambda_{2}= i$

$$V_{2}=\begin{pmatrix} i \\ -1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

$\lambda_{3}= -i$ 
$$V_{3}=\begin{pmatrix} i \\ -1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Have you heard of the [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)? You just want to diagonalize the matrix.

Comment: no but i think thats what im supposed to be using, i am asking if the method i described is how i get what im looking for? using what i have been able to glean from that website and my textbook

Comment: Yes, you are doing the process correctly. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get an Eigensystem as follows:

$$\lambda_1 = 1, v_1 = (0, 0, 1)$$

$$\lambda_2 = -i, v_2 = (-i, -1, 1)$$

$$\lambda_3 = i, v_3 = (i, -1, 1)$$

Lets do one example of an eigenvalue/eigenvector for $\lambda = 1$.

We want to solve $(A - \lambda_1 I)v_1 = 0$, so we have:

$$(A - \lambda_1 I)v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & -1 & 0\\ 1 & 1& 0\end{bmatrix}v_1 = 0$$

So, we can choose $v_1 = (0, 0, 1)$. Repeat the process for the other two eigenvalues.

Next, we can write the [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) as:

$$A = P J P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i & i \\ 0 & -1 & -1\\ 1 & 1& 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -i & 0\\ 0 & 0& i\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ \frac{i}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0\\ -\frac{i}{2} & - \frac{1}{2} & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Ok, i think i actually understand, so if we multiple this system out we will have our canonical matrix B?

Comment: The matrix is J - a diagonal matrix.

Comment: uhm why isnt the last entry in the $\lambda=1$ case = 0?

So the canonical jordan form of this is merely just the center matrix J?

Comment: Sorry, I am tired and am making foolish errors. Don't want a zero eigenvector and yes, J is the matrix.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH YOU HAVE NO idea how long me and my friend have been staring at this problem for. ty sir! sorry for caps but i feel they were needed.

Comment: You are very welcome - bedtime!

Comment: Wonderful FEEDBACK from the OP!!! +1

Comment: Go for it, and crack it! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*:$$\det(A-aI)=\det\begin{pmatrix} -a&1&0 \\ -1&-a&0\\ 1&1&1-a\end{pmatrix}=(1-a)(1+a^2)$$ then eigen value are $1$,$i$,-$i$ then find

*Edit1*: let $v_1$ is eigen vector corespond to$ 1$ and $V_i=v'+iv''$ is eigen vector corespond to $i$  then $T:=(v_1, v', v'')$

Comment: yeah i know im just not sure if the method is right to solve this or not?

Especially the RREF form of A and the eigenvectors being the matrix T

I have never had an explanation of what it is that im supposed to do so the simplest possible most basic thing you'd think anyone would know i will probably find very helpful.

Comment: yes your method is right